# How to update App Store/iTunes Connect icon for my iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunesartwork

I want to update the APP ICON of my iOS application and I updated the images in my Xcode project's asset catalog. But the old image still reflects in App store and iTunes Connect. From the Human Interface Guidelines, I see that we need a icon of 1024*1024 size.

[image]

But there is no place in asset catalog to add a 1024*1024 image. **Where do I add the app store icon?**

Is there any way to update it directly from iTunes Connect?

Comment: To whomsoever concerned, it's not ethical to down vote without proper explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your cursor on the App icon in iTunes Connect:

And delete your old app icon by tapping the red icon at the top-left corner.

Then you can upload the new icon of your app.

[image]

---->

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Johnny. But, is it not possible to change the icon when a new version of my app is pending for developer release? Why because I have a pending to release version and I'm not getting the minus (-) symbol above the app icon.

Comment: Yes, unless you reject the current version and submit it again, as Apple described in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html

The app info isn't editable in `Pending Developer Release` state.

Comment: Ohh okay. But what if I release the new version. Can I change the app icon after that?

Comment: Of course you can, after release the new version, you can add a new version on iTunes Connect, the state will become `Prepare for Submission`, you can edit any info you want.

Comment: I just got a doubt. Actually my new version is already reviewed by Apple  and it's just pending for release. So, if I reject the binary now, will I be able to submit the same binary or I will have to upload a new one?

Comment: In my experience, unless Apple reject the binary, otherwise you can submit the same binary even if it's reviewed by Apple. (I can't guarantee, you must try it on your own risk)